Disabling the automatic build of a package on Hackage
I have a package that fails to get built by the Hackage automatic builder, because the builder runs with an outdated version of a C-library that my package depends on. I want to get rid of the misleading and uninviting "Build Failed" badge.
As I see in packages like lens and aeson they've managed to disable these builds and hence the badge altogether. There's only the "documentation" status badge. How can I do the same?

Turns out the trick is to manually generate the docs and upload them to Hackage right after publishing the package. Then the automatic builder will not get triggered.
It can be done with series of commands like the following:
cabal sdist
cabal upload dist-newstyle/sdist/<pkg-1.2.3>.tar.gz --publish

cabal build --enable-documentation --haddock-for-hackage
cabal sdist
cabal upload dist-newstyle/sdist/<pkg-1.2.3>.tar.gz --publish --documentation

Or using CI/CD with an action like this one.
